# String.Normalize equvilent on Windows Phone for Unicode composition

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, utf-8

I am looking for something to the [String.Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eaxk1x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function that is available in .Net for most platforms but not for Windows Phone. When possible, I am looking to compose a letter and a combining diacritic into a single code point and String.Normalize (which is a wrapper around Normalization class which is also unavailable on WP) would do this for me.

For example, I need to convert the string "a\u0301" to "á" or "\u0e1"

It appears the NLS library isn't part of WP so I am looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UnicodeNormalization](https://github.com/Turo-NET/UnicodeNormalization) library in Windows Phone. After you include it, you use it exactly like you would with the native method.